# Pygame Sprites bug?

Tags: python, pygame

HeyGuys! I just joined this site, so go easy on me with how I go about this question.

So, I recently started playing around with PyGames and ran a few tests with the pygame.sprite.Sprite modules. Here is my code:

```
#Game

import pygame

pygame.init()

screen_width, screen_height = 800, 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width,screen_height))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
red = (255,0,0)
green = (0,255,0)
blue = (0,0,255)

class Block( pygame.sprite.Sprite ):
    def __init__(self, block_color = white, block_width = 64, block_height = 64):
        super(Block, self).__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface((block_width, block_height))
        self.image.fill(block_color)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def set_position(self, x, y):
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y

    def change_color(self, color):
        self.image.fill(color)

    def load_image(self, url):
        self.image = pygame.image.load(url)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

block_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
a_block = Block(green)
b_block = Block(red)
c_block = Block(blue)
d_block = Block()
a_block.set_position(0,0)
b_block.set_position(0,64)
c_block.set_position(64,0)
d_block.set_position(64,64)
d_block.load_image("brick.png")

block_group.add(a_block,b_block,c_block,d_block)

running = True
while running:
    screen.fill(black)
    block_group.draw(screen)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(10)
```

As you can infer already, I intended to create [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHXaQ.png), but instead get 
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCTTV.png) which are both wrong. The strange thing is is that every time I run the file, #1 and #2 are drawn whimsically without a pattern, so I'm wondering if it has anything to do with the way I'm updating the screen in my running while loop.

Any thoughts on how I can fix this? Thanks in advance and I hope to use this site more often!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call

```
def load_image(self, url):
    self.image = pygame.image.load(url)
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
```

you set the rectangle of the Sprite to the rectangle of the image. However, that rectangle has the position (0,0). This means both the green rectangle and the block are being drawn at (0,0).

A sprite group does not necessarily preserve the order of the Sprites, which accounts for the behavior why you see #1 (`block_d` being drawn last) or #2 (`block_a` being drawn last).

Reverse your image load and position setting code and you should be good to go.

```
block_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
a_block = Block(green)
b_block = Block(red)
c_block = Block(blue)
d_block = Block()
d_block.load_image("brick.png")
a_block.set_position(0,0)
b_block.set_position(0,64)
c_block.set_position(64,0)
d_block.set_position(64,64)

block_group.add(a_block,b_block,c_block,d_block)
```

If you need a Sprite group that preserves the order in which the Sprites were added, you can use `pygame.sprite.OrderedUpdates`.

Comment: Thanks for the insightful answer, now my code is working as I wanted :^).

Comment: Glad I could help and welcome to StackOverflow! If this solved your problem, you might consider accepting this answer as the correct answer using the checkmark so others know your problem has been solved. :)